# How to delete allocated variable passed as a constructor parameter in c++

Tags: c++

I' am  new at c++ and I'am  learning about memory allocation using "new" and "delete"

I got this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Obj1
{
public:
    Obj1(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y)
    {}

    int getX(){return m_x;}
    int getY(){return m_y;}

private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};

class Obj2
{
public:
    Obj2(Obj1* a): m_x(a->getX()), m_y(a->getY())
    {}

    int getX(){return m_x;}
    int getY(){return m_y;}

private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};

int main()
{
    Obj2 a(new Obj1(1, 2));

    std::cout << a.getX() << std::endl;//displays 1
    std::cout << a.getY() << std::endl;//displays 2

    return 0;
 }
```

It works just fine, but how do I delete allocated "Obj1"?

you may suggest  this code:

```
Obj1* b;
b = new Obj1(1, 2);
Obj2 a(b);
```

then

```
delete b;
```

But how to do it with:

```
 Obj2 a(new Obj1(1, 2));
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't. You have a memory leak. You also have no reason to use `new` here.

Comment: You need to think about *ownership*. Is the `Obj2` going to *own* the pointer and be responsible to delete it? If not, your second example is not correct (leaks memory). If so, your first example is not correct (double deletion).

Comment: No reason to use pointers period here.

Comment: What if I do this: "Obj1* c;" and "Obj2 a(c=new Obj1(1, 2));" then "delete c;" will this work?

Comment: @westiti: Yes, but _why?_  There's no reason to use `new` here.

Comment: I know it's just another way to do things

Answer (score 1):

```
Obj2 a( std::make_shared<Obj1>( 1, 2 ).get() );
```

You must have something that owns the dynamically allocated Obj1 and can cause it to be deleted. [`std::make_shared<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) can be used to make a `shared_ptr`, which in this case is a temp and exists only for the duration of the Obj2 constructor call.

Of course, there's also the simpler

```
int main()
{
    Obj1 aa( 1, 2 );
    Obj2 a( &aa );

    std::cout << a.getX() << std::endl;//displays 1
    std::cout << a.getY() << std::endl;//displays 2

    return 0;
}
```

which uses no dynamic allocation at all. Both objects are automatic.

Comment: hmm.  `Obj2 a(&static_cast<Obj1&>(Obj1(1,2)));`  seems like a bad idea, though interesting.

Comment: He seems to *really* want to use dynamic allocation for Obj1 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your Obj2 class, I would suggest, instead of having `m_x` and `m_y`, use a variable like `m_obj` that stores the pointer to your newly allocated Obj1 object. Then, provide a destructor for Obj2 that uses `delete` to deallocate the memory pointed to by `m_obj`. Finally, alter your getX() and getY() methods appropriately to access.

In the future, however, I would not recommend using dynamically allocated memory for situations like this, simply because it can become unnecessarily complicated. Instead, I would recommend using a reference, and not worry about using a pointer unless absolutely necessary.